# Total value with JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, post

I'm using [this form script](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml) to automatically calculate totals. Now I need to get that total and add it to a database via PHP and MySQL.

I don't know how to 'name' the `totalPrice` div, so that I can pass its value to the database.

**Edit:**

I'm still not getting results in the database. I'm now using `$_POST[totalValue]` for the field set and `totalPrice` for the field name.

HTML:

```
<div id="totalPrice"></div></div>
<input type="hidden" name="totalValue" id="totalValue" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#vendorform").submit(function(){
    var totalValue = document.getElementById('totalValue');
    totalValue.value = vendorPrice; //the actual total value
});

function calculateTotal()
{
    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var vendorPrice = getTentPrice() + getElecPrice() + getPropanePrice();

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price Vendor $"+vendorPrice;
}
```

Comment: Usually it's not a good idea to insert calculated value within a table.

Comment: Oh, why not? And what is my alternative?

Comment: Because this practice violates normalisation rules and must be used only in particular conditions to increase performance. In all the other cases it's better to calculate them with a query, not to store them.

Comment: The person who will be access this info in a csv will not have the knowledge to calculate w/ a query. I need to be able to save a calculated total that is pre-totaled as the user completes the form and is easily viewable by a non-nerd.

Comment: Why don't you create 'export' action that will generate csv and calculate totals on the fly?

Comment: I'd like that but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vendorPrice` variable is not available outside the scope of the function `calculateTotal`. You could make `vendorPrice` a global variable, but that's a bit of an ugly hack.

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var vendorPrice = getTentPrice() + getElecPrice() + getPropanePrice();
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price Vendor $"+vendorPrice;

    return vendorPrice; // <-- ADDED
}
```

And this:

```
$("#vendorform").submit(function(){
    var totalValue = document.getElementById('totalValue');
    totalValue.value = calculateTotal(); // <-- CHANGED
});
```

This way, you assign the value that is now returned by `calculateTotal()`  to `totalValue.value`.

By the way: since it looks like you're already using jQuery, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
// [...]

var divobj = $('#totalPrice');
divobj.css('display', 'block');
divobj.text("Total Price Vendor $"+vendorPrice);

// [...]

var totalValue = $('#totalValue');
totalValue.val(calculateTotal());
```

This makes it a bit more readable (although that's debatable) and a bit more cross-browser reliant. jQuery has great docs (e.g. [the documentation on .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)). If you're going to use jQuery more often I can highly recommend bookmarking the docs and skimming through them.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to play w/ this after dinner :)

Comment: Thank you, thank you. This is working for me. I'm going to go back and do it properly (calculate w/ query per the other suggestions) but this is great for now.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#cakeform").submit(function(){
    var price = $("#totalPrice").text().replace(/[\s\S]+\$/,"")
    $("#cakeForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="estimated_price" value="' + price + '" />')   
})
```

But as @nick-rulez pointed out, is usually not a good idea to save calculated values in a database.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="totalValue" id="totalValue" />
```

Which you have to put inside your `<form>...</form>`.
When you submit the form you're going to receive input's value.

You can set the value to the hidden field with this sniped:

**JS**

```
var totalValue = document.getElementById('totalValue');
totalValue.value = myValue; //myValue is the total
```

Comment: I'm gonna cry- you're being so helpful and I'm still getting 0 in my totalPrice field in the database. I'm not giving up yet- I just don't have much brain left to wrap around this problem.

Comment: $_POST['totalValue']; must be the value you're looking for.

Comment: I'm assuming that the myValue should be vendorPrice per the js (see my edit in OP) but it's still returning 0...

Comment: thank you mgechev- I know I will be looking back at your tips for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var Price = getTshirtPrice() + getTshirtType() + getTshirtColour() +
    getTextColour();

    var divobj = document.getElementById('textbox');
    divobj.value = "Total Price For the T-shirt: £"+Price;

    return Price;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="totalPrice"><input type="text" id="textbox"></div>
```

Do that. It works perfectly fine.